# XCTestExpectation - Calling an async method twice causes API violation

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, xctest

I’m writing unit tests in swifts, and testing a unique workflow.

1. In methodA(), I load an object incorrectly (say with incorrect credentials) using an async method. Also kick off an expectation

   ```
       func methodA(withCred credential: NSURLCredential) {
       var objA = ObjectA()
       // Set objA.a, objA.b, objA.c, 
       objA.credential = credential //Incorrect credential First time, Correct Credential second time 
       objA.delegate = self 
       expectation = expectationWithDescription(“Aync”)
       objA.callAsyncMethod() //This fires successDelegate() or failureDelegate()}
   ```
2. When FailureDelegate() is fired, I reload the object, correctly this time. In order do so, I need to call MethodA() again (so I can reuse all the other stuff there).

   ```
   func failureDelegate(error: NSError!) {

   XCTAssertTrue(error.localizedDescription == “Invalid Credentials“)
   //Now that I’ve verified correct error is returned, I need to reload objA
   methodA(withCred:correctCredential) 
   }

   func successDelegate(obj : ObjectA) {
     XCTAssert(“Object is loaded”)
     expectation.fulfill()
   }
   ```

3.This kicks off the same expectation again in methodA, and results in the following error:

> API violation - creating expectations while already in waiting mode.

I understand this is not permitted by swift. Is there a workaround or better way to test these kinds of async methods looping with Swift using XCTest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't share instances of `expectation` across tests. You should be declaring `expectation` (i.e. with `let`) in the body of each test, not as a property on `XCTestCase`. If you really need to use the delegation pattern (closures would be much, much simpler and more conventional), you can pass that as an additional parameter to your delegate method.

Comment: Thanks, In this case, the result remains the same whether or not `expectation` is a property on `XCTestCase`The test requires loading the resource twice (calling an async method twice), and kicks of the same expectation. I could possibly do a if loop, but for hundreds of test cases, i was wondering if there might be a more elegant solution. It's an SDK that I'm testing, and we are gradually moving towards blocks - need to maintain delegates until then.

Comment: Can you help me understand why it is not recommended to declare expectations as properties on `XCTestCase`? It seems to be working as expected so far, and I'm wondering if I'm missing some caveat?

Comment: @SuPotter Storing the expectations to a property will violate the isolation of the test cases. Imagine your setting the self.expectation property in every test case but you forget a single one. In this case you can not rely on your compiler to tell you that you forgot to setup the expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code exemple is incomplete, could you provide the full code?

As @mattt said each test should preferably be unique and should not reuse other test variable.

Regarding your issue, you should declare all your expectation first before the triggering `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:`. You can't not create a new expectation after you've start waiting for another one.